# Await SyntaxError in nodeJS: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

It may sound silly, but I can't find why I am getting this error:-

> C:\node-project\api.testsite\seed\index.js:20
> await User.create(user);
> ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level
> bodies of modules
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at Object. (C:\node-project\api.testsite\database\connection.js:2:21)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)

This is my code. It's pretty simple.

```
const moment     = require("moment");
const bc         = require("bcryptjs");

var userList     = require("./users");
var User         = require("../app/Models/User");

module.exports = {
  seedUser: async function (db) {
    const Users = db.collection("users");
    const userCount = await User.count();
    if (userCount === 0) {
      userList.map((user) => {
        console.log(user, 'hioo')
        const DtCr = new Date();
        user.created_date = DtCr;
        user.modified_date = DtCr;
        user.created_at = moment().valueOf();
        user.updated_at = moment().valueOf();
        console.log(user)
        await User.create(user);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

As you see, the function `seedUser` is itself an `async` function. Moreover, the loc:-

```
const userCount = await User.count();
```

isn't causing any error. Then why the line:-

```
await User.create(user);
```

is causing error? If the error is due to await inside function seedUser, then shouldn't both have the same issue?

Comment: It’s not in an async function—the function used in `map`. Like the error says.

Comment: I was trying to write a "more correct" solution here, but it's not clear exactly what this code is supposed to do and/or how this is called.  Does the calling code do anything if the promise rejects that this code returns? What is `userList` and where does it come from?  What should this code do if an error happened on `User.create(user)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map function

```js
//           v missing async here
userList.map((user) => {
        console.log(user, 'hioo')
        const DtCr = new Date();
        user.created_date = DtCr;
        user.modified_date = DtCr;
        user.created_at = moment().valueOf();
        user.updated_at = moment().valueOf();
        console.log(user)
        await User.create(user);
      });
```

Is not a async function. Doing

```js
//           vvvvv missing this async
userList.map(async (user) => {
        console.log(user, 'hioo')
        const DtCr = new Date();
        user.created_date = DtCr;
        user.modified_date = DtCr;
        user.created_at = moment().valueOf();
        user.updated_at = moment().valueOf();
        console.log(user)
        await User.create(user);
      });
```

will fix the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was so silly of me. I couldn't even find out the issue.

Comment: @Saswat - Well, that makes the warning go away. It doesn't do anything useful with the `await` because await inside the `.map()` callback doesn't actually do anything useful. It doesn't make the `.map()` iteration actually wait. And there is no error handling on the `await User.create(user)` either so any error there will go unhandled. **This is not a proper solution.**    The OP could just remove the `await` in front of `User.create(user)` and that would work just as well as this.  But neither is a proper solution.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you please suggest something that would be more appropriate in my case? I would be highly grateful.